# Tomcat user file access rights

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, beagleboneblack

I have a tomcat web application running in a beagle bone black.
Inside this application, some pins can be controlled:

```
private static final String GPIO_DIR = "/sys/class/gpio";

public static void enablePin(int gpio)
{

    try (RandomAccessFile out = new RandomAccessFile(new File(GPIO_DIR
            + "/export"), "rw"))
    {
        out.write(("" + gpio).getBytes());
    } catch (IOException io)
    {
        //possibly the pin was already enabled
        log.trace("Not able to enable pin", io);            
    }
}
```

The problem is that the files in gpio folder are protected.

How can I configure the access rights of tomcat7 to be able to access those files.

The current access rights of export are

```
ls -l
--w------ 1 root root .....
```

If I change the access rights with chmod, they will be set to default after restarting the system.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=112895) an alternative for you?

Comment: Seems like there isn't a permanent way to set it.Permissions are stored in inode.http://www.slashroot.in/inode-and-its-structure-linux